# Frontend application to backend server websocket connections can have one producer

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, websocket, mutex, producer-consumer

I am working on frontend application, where front end application sends video (live) frames to backend server, backend server processes the video frames and sends the data(text) back to front end application via websocket connection. On backend websocket server side, whenever client sends video frames, these frames are added to the queue along with connection id. Is it possible to write a method which polls the queue, process the frames and generate the text data for specific client which will be sent to the client. This method should have one instance only and should be shared by all websocket connections. The method uses the shared variables and should have exclusive access. I can't mix frames from different client to generate text data.
If I write a producer then each client connection will have separate producer and these producers will use shared variable which is not desired. Right now I wrote websocket connection without consumer-producer and put lock around the critical code. But it doesn't seem good solution. Backend is in python and front end in reactjs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using a Dictionary seems sensible.

Comment: can you please elaborate @AluanHaddad

Comment: yes, it makes more sense to store the video frames per connection in the dictionary than queue.    I put the code to process the frames independent of websocket connection as follows.            
 `start_server = websockets.serve(
    asl_video, "0.0.0.0", 8766, ssl=ssl_context, ping_interval=30, ping_timeout=30, max_size=None
)

#ssl=ssl_context,
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(data_process())` but in this case on client gets the error 'WebSocket opening handshake timed out'

Comment: Add that to the question